# Synchronize Scrolling over mapped React Components

Tags: reactjs, scroll, mapping

I am trying to synchronize scrolling in my React page. As you can see, I have a div-container containing an arbitrary number of one Component, depending on the length of the array. I've tried react-scroll-sync and scroll-sync-react, but to no avail... Any ideas?

Edit: to be more precise, there is an iframe in each component that is the scrollable part.

```js
<div>
        {array.map((value, index) => (
          <MyComponent style={{ overflow: 'auto' }} />
        ))}
</div>
```

I tried the following: Removing the Component and just producing arr.length-times iframes. But that also didn't work:

```js
import "./styles.css";
// import { ScrollSync, ScrollSyncNode } from "scroll-sync-react";
import { ScrollSync, ScrollSyncPane } from "react-scroll-sync";

const arr = [1, 2, 3];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ScrollSync>
      <div
        className="App"
        style={{ display: "flex", height: "500px", width: "500px" }}
      >
        {arr.map((element, index) => (
          <ScrollSyncPane key={arr[index]}>
            <iframe
              src={mySource}
              key={arr[index]}
              title={arr[index]}
              styles={{ height: "300px", width: "200px", overflow: "auto" }}
            />
          </ScrollSyncPane>
        ))}
      </div>
    </ScrollSync>
  );
}
```

Comment: Try to add max-height and overflow-y: 'auto' to your container